# HTML Form in table does not send all avaiable data via POST

Tags: php, post

I have a table with 113 rows in it.
Every row have 9 cells, where is an input in it, like on this shema:

```
row_1[td_1],row_1[td_2],[...],
row_2[td_1],row_2[td_2],[...],
row_3[td_1],row_3[td_2],[...]
[...]
row_113[td_1],row_113[td_2],[...]
```

The problem: when I'm sending this data via POST, I'm only getting data up to the first field of row_112:

```
[...]  
["row_111"]=>
  array(9) {
    ["tytul"]=>
    string(15) "example element"
    ["pkwiu"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["jm"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["ilosc"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["cena_brutto"]=>
    string(5) "74.00"
    ["vat"]=>
    string(3) "23%"
    ["vat_oryginalny"]=>
    string(2) "23"
    ["cena_netto"]=>
    string(5) "60.16"
    ["wartosc_brutto"]=>
    string(5) "74.00"
  }
  ["row_112"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["tytul"]=>
    string(15) "example element" <------
  }
```

Why am I not receiving the full form data?

The example is avaiable here:
http://pastebin.com/ahVqUetJ

On top of script I've just put simply:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0) {
        var_dump($_POST);
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: i don't get the problem - all your input rows are being submited and listed correctly

Comment: @ulkas, no they are not. Please read the question better.

Comment: Is HTML correctness wrapping form has effect for POST data also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because from `PHP 5.3.9` they added a limit for [max_input_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#max_input_vars), and that limit is 1000.

From your form with 111 rows you get `111*9=999 + 1`  (1 from `row_112`) resulting `1000` variables.

Change in `php.ini`:

```
max_input_vars = 3000
suhosin.post.max_vars = 3000
suhosin.request.max_vars = 3000
suhosin.get.max_vars = 3000
```

or from php:

```
ini_set('max_input_vars', 3000);
```

or any limit you want.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, now I have to wait for server administrator action. This limit could cause many problems for a lot of scripts like mine, don't you think?